# How to access a directory outside docker context in a docker File?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have an application in .net core 3.1 and I am building a docker file to put the application in a container, when I try to build the image I get the following error:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "ApiDigitalGamesMx/ApiDigitalGamesMx.csproj"' returned a non- 
zero code: 1
```

I run this command:

```
docker build -t image-netcore:1.0 .
```

And this is my dockerFile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ApiDigitalGamesMx/ApiDigitalGamesMx.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "ApiDigitalGamesMx/ApiDigitalGamesMx.csproj"
COPY ["ApiProducts.Library/ApiProducts.Library.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "ApiProducts.Library/ApiProducts.Library.csproj"
COPY . .

RUN dotnet build "ApiDigitalGamesMx/ApiDigitalGamesMx.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
RUN dotnet build "ApiProducts.Library/ApiProducts.Library.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ApiDigitalGamesMx/ApiDigitalGamesMx.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
RUN dotnet publish "ApiProducts.Library/ApiProducts.Library.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ApiDigitalGamesMx.dll"]
```

Is there any kind of solution that I can implement?

Comment: By definition, you can't access a file outside the build context at build time. The context is written to a tar file that's sent to the Docker engine to build your image. The engine can't access anything outside of that context. Instead, provide a build context that includes the files you want to copy. (i.e. instead of `.` provide `/some/path/`.

Comment: @tentative Can I write 2 paths in the same line?, i have two different folders?

Comment: can you explain what you mean by 2 paths in the same line? If you provide a different build context, you can adjust all your `COPY` lines to the relative path of your build context and then access any folder with the build context as your "working directory" in the Dockerfile.

Comment: yes you can copy 2 paths in the same line e.g. `COPY ./*.sln ./*/*.csproj ./`. As you can see you can also use wildcards...

Comment: I´m using this command `docker build -t image-netcore:1.0 ./ApiDigitalGamesMx
` but i have two folders, ApiDigitalGamesMx and ApiProducts.Library, How can I get both folders to be searched?

Comment: Also I don't know if your title of the question aligns with the actual question...

Comment: can you move your Dockerfile to the same directory that has the ApiDigitalGamesMx & ApiProducts sub dirs? then you could just do `docker build -t image-netcore:1.0 .` and do the copy as `COPY ./*/*.csproj ./`... if the parent dir has a bunch of files/dirs that you don't want included you can implement a .dockerignore file